# Is it possible to pattern match on a function type?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a mini-language, and I have a situation where I'm trying to process an abstract syntax tree such that it either returns an exception, or a function which will resolve to a bool. Here's a minimal example:

```
data MyException = Can'tResolveToBool

data InputToBeAddedLater =
    InputToBeAddedLater String

data Exp a =
    ReturnsBoolFunc String (Exp a)
    | IsBool Bool
    | ReturnsExpFunc String (Exp a)

resolveToExp :: String -> Exp a -> (InputToBeAddedLater -> Exp a)
resolveToExp funcName arg
    | funcName == "patently_false" = (\_ -> IsBool False)

resolveToBool :: Exp a -> Either MyException Bool
resolveToBool (ReturnsBoolFunc funcName (ReturnsExpFunc fn arg)) =
    let resolved = resolveToExp fn arg
    in case resolved of
        ((InputToBeAddedLater _) -> (IsBool bool)) -> Right bool
        ((InputToBeAddedLater _) -> (ReturnsExpFunc _ _)) -> Left Can'tResolveToBool
```

The last line is my (sadly, non-functional) attempt to pattern match on a function type. GHC recommends I try the `ViewPatterns` extension, but looking briefly at this, I'm not sure that it's what I need. Is it conceptually impossible to do what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: In your code you use `(\_ -> IsBool False)`, but it could have been `(\arg -> if condition arg then IsBool False else ...)` and in such case it's not obvious how the "pattern matching one function" should work. Functions can only be used in one way in Haskell: calling them, providing one of its arguments.

Comment: @chi Yes - in the real-life situation, `resolveToExp` returns all variants of `Exp a`. My assumption was that if this works, then the `case` match in `resolveToBool` would be fully filled out. So another case of `resolved` would be, say, `((InputToBeAddedLater _) -> (ReturnsExpFunc _ _)) -> Right True`.

Comment: But if the function returns sometimes `IsBool` sometimes `ReturnsExpFunc`, depending on the input-to-be-added, pattern matching can not choose between these two branches. The only way you can use such a function is `case resolved someInputValueHere of IsBool _ -> ... ; ReturnsExpFunc _ _ -> ...` where you have to choose a specific input value. You can't test the result of the function if you don't call it passing a concrete argument.

Comment: I can give you a function pattern matcher if you give me a solver for the halting problem.

Comment: @chi My original question was 'is this possible' and it sounds like your answer is 'no', so thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: If you want to be able to ensure that a function in your mini language ought to return a boolean value *without* calling your function on any particular argument, the kind of tool you would normally use to do that is a **type system** rather than pattern matching. Inspecting every possible code path through a function to test whether its return value always has some property is extremely difficult (impossible under many circumstances), but adopting rules of construction so that your functions have a known return type is much more doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify the question dramatically. This is the core of your question: can I implement `desired`?

```
desired :: (String -> Bool) -> Bool
desired f = case f of
    (_ -> True ) -> True
    (_ -> False) -> False
```

Hopefully with all of the chaff winnowed away it's clear that there's no way this can be done: there is not necessarily a fact of the matter about whether `f` returns `True` or `False`. The value it returns is allowed to depend on what input you pass it!

Comment: yes, thank you - this neatly shows why the idea of matching on the return type constructor is conceptually impossible and so a non-starter.

Answer (score 2):

What, as I understand it, you try to express with the pattern

```
  case resolved of
    ((InputToBeAddedLater _) -> (IsBool bool)) -> ...
```

is to check whether `resolved` returns *for any input* something with the outer constructor `IsBool`. I.e. whether it is of the form

```
resolved (InputToBeAddedLater i) = IsBool (...)
```

This you can at least *validate* without needing to provide a concrete `i`, thanks to non-strictness:

```
  case resolved (InputToBeAddedLater undefined) of
    (IsBool bool) -> Right bool
    (ReturnsExpFunc _ _) -> Left Can'tResolveToBool
```

The problem with this is that it blows up if `resolved` actually evaluates its argument before providing an outer constructor, for example

```
resolved (InputToBeAddedLater "") = IsBool False
resolved (InputToBeAddedLater s) = ReturnsExpFunc "" (IsBool True)
```

You could now add some error-catching mechanism on top of this, but that can only really be done in IO and is anyways hacky.

Really, I think this is an XY question, and what you should actually do is give `resolved` a way to signal its result's outer constructor without having any input at all. This can be achieved by generalising `Exp` so it *includes* the `InputToBeAddedLater`, but only after revealing the outermost constructor:

```
data ExpH m a
  = ReturnsBoolFunc (m (String, Exp a))
  | IsBool (m Bool)
  | ReturnsExpFunc (m (String, Exp a))

type Exp = ExpH Identity

resolveToExp :: String -> Exp a -> ExpH ((->) InputToBeAddedLater) a
resolveToExp funcName arg
    | funcName == "patently_false" = IsBool (const False)

resolveToBool :: Exp a -> Either MyException Bool
resolveToBool (ReturnsBoolFunc funcName (Identity (ReturnsExpFunc fn arg)))
   = case resolveToExp fn arg of
        IsBool b -> Right (b undefined) -- here you would actually provide an argument
        ReturnsExpFunc _ -> Left Can'tResolveToBool
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like a real solution, I'll have a think about whether to take this route since I suspect it's leading me into deeper waters than I'm equipped to go.

Answer (score 1):

As a general answer it is possible to pattern match on some functions, a representable functor like `(Tag ->)` is isomorphic to `Vector 3`:

```hs
type Tag :: Type
data Tag = FirstNameTag | LastNameTag | AddressTag

type Person :: Type
type Person = Tag -> String

personToTuple :: Person -> (String, String, String)
personToTuple person = (person FirstNameTag, person LastNameTag, person AddressTag)

pattern FirstName :: String -> Person
pattern FirstName firstName <- (personToTuple -> (firstName, _, _))

pattern LastName :: String -> Person
pattern LastName lastName <- (personToTuple -> (_, lastName, _))

pattern Address :: String -> Person
pattern Address address <- (personToTuple -> (_, _, address))
```

Comment: thanks for this. If I'm understanding correctly, it seems like the reason that your example  is possible, but my original idea is impossible, is that in this example you are pattern matching on the type `(String, String, String)`, rather than on trying to match on constructors of a particular `data` type.

Comment: That's right. It works for certain functions as isomorphic to datatypes that can be pattern-matched on. But here it makes more sense to create a restricted language which is easier to reason about like leftaroundabout suggested